# Failed to insert data into mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I try to use java code to insert data into the mysql database. I built a user table in the database. User table has 4 fields：id, username, password and address.

```
mysql> desc user;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address  | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is my java code.

```
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybatis?serverTimezone=UTC";
        String mysqlUserName = "root";
        String mysqlPassword = "123456";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, mysqlUserName, mysqlPassword);
        String sql = "INSERT INTO user(username,password,address) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1,"11dsa1");
        stmt.setString(2,"111");
        stmt.setString(3,"111");
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if (conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){

        }
        try {
            if (stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){

        }
    }
```

**No error occurred**.
But there is no data in my database.

```
mysql> select * from user; 
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

But I can insert data by the shell.

```
mysql> insert into user(username,password,address) values ("aaa","aaa","aaa");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> select * from user;
+----+----------+----------+---------+
| id | username | password | address |
+----+----------+----------+---------+
| 22 | aaa      | aaa      | aaa     |
+----+----------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But **the id is 22 not 1 !**

Actually **I have run this java code 21 times before**. My understanding is that this java code can insert data into mysql, but immediately remove the data from the database. 
I really can't understand this ridiculous situation

Comment: Never catch exceptions without handle it

Comment: You never execute the prepared Statement

Comment: Use try-with-resources instead of closing Statement and Connection in finally

Comment: If you close the statement in finally you must not close it in try block

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your comment. I will follow these rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did not you forget to actually execute the statement?

Before closing it just put [stmt.executeUpdate()](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) so it is

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user(username,password,address) VALUES (?,?,?)";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1,"11dsa1");
stmt.setString(2,"111");
stmt.setString(3,"111");
stmt.executeUpdate()
```

I also would advise you to close your prepared statement in a finally block or if you use java 7+ take a look how you can use prepared statements with try-with-resources [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Also if you close your connection in finally block, why would you want to close it in **try** block as well(last command)? It is absolutely redundant.

In general keeping you code clean would allow you to read it better and thus to better see possible issues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggession. In fact, I can't insert data to mysql when using mybatis. Then I wrote this script to test if my database link is OK. But I forgot to add the line stmt.executeUpdate(). Based on your suggestion, I have checked my code that used mybatis before. Sure enough, I forgot to add the line sqlSession.commit().

Comment: It was kind of clear that your code is an attempt to quickly check something. Just to stress it out, I still believe my comment about the clear code is valid because when one tries something. Usually we try something when it is not clear how this 'something' works or if it even works. I think lready enough not clear things so something were additionally hidden under a not clear code.

Comment: I also was going to write that your code will work only in case you have autocommit enabled for mysql otherwise you would need to commit explicitly, but then I decided that it is out of the topic of your question. Did not guess it properly, sorry, man :)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Before your `stmt.close()` add this..

```
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

It should work!!

**Suggestion:**

Also, if you are on Java version higher than 6, you should go for try-with resources approach that manages the crucial resource in smarter way. !!

Comment: executeupdate must be called *before* the statement is closed. not after. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) `Throws:
SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed PreparedStatement or the SQL statement returns a ResultSet object`

Comment: Thanks @Jens for correction on `preparedStaement`, but look carefully, I said higher than 6.

Comment: @user9887555 it was for the user who down voted, not for you :) , as a community work it is equally inportant to comment on down votes, so I asked them to explain their vote cast. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Before `stmt.close();`, add this `stmt.executeupdate();` because you should update your table then you should update your queries.